# Zoom is very slow in ChartJS Zoom Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I'm trying to build a webpage with some graphs. In order to get it, I'm using ChartJS. Sometimes can happen there are too many data to see in just one canvas, so I need to use the ChartJS zoom plugin. I install and use it well, unless I have a big problem:
Setting the mode as 'x', the zoom applied on canvas is really really slow (even if I put 100000 as speed value). I want to make it faster. How can I solve it? This is my code:

```js
  new Chart(document.getElementById('like-growth-lt'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515],
      datasets: [{
          data: [64, 44, 71, 71, 24, 32, 54, 56, 36, 37, 50, 38, 48, 33, 46, 88, 43, 45, 48, 36, 44, 38, 64, 63, 89, 40, 50, 85, 79, 69, 64, 70, 66, 70, 40, 178, 57, 25, 38, 105, 79, 58, 89, 102, 94, 87, 91, 93, 100, 72, 78, 65, 68, 123, 79, 107, 91, 66, 89, 90, 45, 127, 138, 79, 58, 81, 92, 97, 52, 97, 43, 64, 81, 62, 69, 74, 75, 54, 93, 43, 101, 83, 49, 106, 77, 86, 105, 91, 73, 129, 99, 64, 104, 92, 105, 141, 96, 100, 84, 101, 75, 100, 76, 112, 171, 94, 78, 97, 87, 100, 198, 112, 98, 95, 127, 107, 74, 122, 137, 45, 147, 147, 169, 125, 147, 129, 118, 164, 90, 135, 132, 135, 135, 239, 197, 165, 261, 150, 164, 238, 271, 196, 307, 246, 137, 112, 142, 265, 295, 173, 172, 116, 127, 141, 142, 134, 196, 298, 305, 273, 121, 99, 108, 138, 191, 310, 375, 360, 427, 271, 191, 168, 123, 323, 70, 126, 138, 222, 170, 160, 185, 236, 160, 290, 192, 196, 386, 166, 186, 236, 232, 425, 181, 142, 103, 126, 176, 292, 200, 186, 179, 277, 305, 610, 140, 200, 283, 218, 384, 183, 165, 156, 195, 215, 210, 157, 337, 208, 799, 130, 242, 80, 337, 181, 261, 307, 264, 371, 639, 379, 253, 384, 141, 391, 212, 1371, 321, 149, 345, 345, 159, 337, 313, 1131, 204, 339, 396, 208, 285, 99, 440, 410, 187, 138, 109, 241, 318, 225, 415, 350, 231, 267, 432, 195, 228, 418, 360, 334, 204, 706, 270, 70, 328, 219, 319, 594, 168, 229, 632, 281, 259, 391, 150, 628, 273, 339, 432, 237, 667, 319, 302, 88, 167, 334, 274, 121, 303, 636, 233, 1399, 465, 404, 211, 209, 537, 361, 192, 189, 474, 1694, 659, 297, 495, 883, 417, 427, 298, 438, 251, 381, 422, 442, 225, 418, 177, 476, 292, 619, 147, 293, 375, 228, 326, 539, 306, 416, 317, 239, 1095, 605, 219, 392, 320, 296, 216, 355, 563, 291, 792, 298, 319, 252, 526, 225, 225, 399, 387, 255, 311, 199, 364, 542, 405, 260, 175, 173, 582, 231, 201, 196, 222, 909, 265, 191, 243, 346, 349, 163, 263, 151, 217, 261, 172, 191, 387, 314, 379, 172, 157, 446, 120, 131, 494, 445, 294, 414, 485, 407, 415, 214, 242, 159, 168, 145, 256, 123, 350, 999, 296, 171, 790, 1051, 620, 330, 231, 1742, 194, 547, 360, 136, 503, 555, 646, 580, 609, 566, 256, 181, 189, 562, 176, 622, 758, 692, 358, 202, 1877, 1157, 668, 311, 1037, 736, 1477, 616, 677, 605, 224, 838, 306, 704, 503, 448, 1198, 778, 171, 921, 1071, 1099, 837, 329, 2337, 395, 1063, 297, 1415, 1195, 745, 341, 931, 1178, 336, 1016, 234, 632, 573, 495, 944, 993, 1066, 1980, 619, 556, 238, 818, 1003, 532, 1427, 373, 249, 304, 790, 2962, 985, 252, 1545, 276, 1219, 1112, 1109, 1367, 792, 1116, 1055, 648, 740, 435, 1528, 805, 565, 1183, 1105, 1498, 1453, 381, 651, 2073],
          label: '',
          borderColor: 'rgb(22, 133, 204)',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(22, 133, 204, 0.3)',
        },
      ]
    },
    options: {
        pan: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: "x",
            speed: 10000000000000000
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            drag: false,
            mode: "x",
            speed: 10000000000000000
        },
        responsive: true
    }
  });
```

```css
  .panel{
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.7"></script>


<div class="panel" id="panel-lt">
    <canvas id="like-growth-lt" ></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Ma be You can try
 `zoom: { enabled: true, drag: false, speed: 0.5, threshold: 2, sensitivity: 3 },`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `scales.xAxes.type` to numeric and then set the speed to `0.1`. Speed is from `0` to `1`, so setting it to `1000000` is useless.